# Unable to process binding Knockout.js magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have created a new theme in Magento 2 and rewritten `minicart.phtml`, but when adding product to cart, mini-cart does not show items and have error JS (knockout.js) like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:getCartParam('items'),as:'item'} }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
>   Message: Cannot read property 'configurable' of undefined

Please help me fix this bug, thanks for all.

Comment: Check you have included the html template correctly in the js file. I believe you're receiving these errors because your js(knockout) and html files can't see each other.

Comment: can you post the changes you made to `minicart.phtml`?

Comment: Please share minicart.phtml file code.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the **minicart.phtml** and **content.html** file from your theme  with core template (**vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart**‌​) , (**vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html**).

**Run the following commands -**

1. rm -rf pub/static/frontend
2. rm -rf var
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

**I hope it will help you.**